# How to specify katalon account name during a CI run

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, katalon-studio

We are running katalon inside jenkins using the official katalon docker container. But the tests fail to start up with the error

```
Trial license is only available for Katalon accounts registered with a business email.
```

We have a katalon account. Where do I specify it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://forum.katalon.com/t/invalid-license-trial-license-is-only-available-for-katalon-accounts-registered-with-a-business-email/40061):

> The trial license is eligible for business email (not a gmail, yahoo, outlook). Are you sure you have used a business email to activate Katalon Studio ? You should go to About dialog and see if there’s text Katalon Studio Enterprise, it would be proof that you’re indeed in the trial.

Comment: I work in devops, not automation. We don't use the studio in devops, just the runtime. Is there no way to check this setting using a command line or even grep?